# Optics Diffraction Grating Plot

Tags: optics

I was unsure whether to post this in physics stackexchange or mathematica stackexchange, so I posted it in both.  I'm trying make an intensity plot for a diffraction grating that contains 100 lines/mm.  Using the equation as a function of theta:

$$I=I_{o}\Bigg[\frac{Sin(\frac{N\pi d Sin\theta}{\lambda})} {Sin(\frac{\pi dSin\theta}{\lambda})}\Bigg]^2     \Bigg[\frac{Sin(\frac{\pi a Sin\theta}{\lambda})} {\frac{\pi a Sin\theta}{\lambda}}\Bigg]^2$$

Where $N$ is the number of slits that is hit by the laser, $d$ is the distance between the slits (.009mm), $a$ is the slit width (.001mm), and $\lambda$ of the laser is 632.8 nm.  The laser diameter is roughly 1mm so I can assume that the laser will be incident upon roughly 100 lines in the grating (N=100). I tried to plot the peak intensities to match my experimental results, but my results do not seem correct.  However, I did  successfully make intensity plots from single slit to 5-slit, so I think my Mathematica code is correct.

```
λ = 632.8;      (*in nm*)
a100 = 1000;    (*in nm*)
d100 = 9000;    (*in nm*)
Plot[
  ((Sin[100*(π*d100)/λ Sin[θ]]/Sin[(π*d100)/λ Sin[θ]])^2) * 
  ((Sin[(π*a100)/λ Sin[θ]]/((π*a100)/λ Sin[θ]))^2), 
  {θ, -.5, .5}, PlotRange -> All
] (*100 lines/mm, function of theta*)
```

This is the result of my plot

[image]

However, my experimental results are 
[image]

Can anyone find a solution to the discrepancy?  I also tried using the equivalent expression as a function of Y 
$$I=I_{o}\Bigg[\frac{Sin(\frac{N\pi d* Y}{\lambda*L})} {Sin(\frac{\pi d*Y}{\lambda*L})}\Bigg]^2     \Bigg[\frac{Sin(\frac{\pi a *Y}{\lambda*L})} {\frac{\pi a *Y}{\lambda*L}}\Bigg]^2$$
 and converted the x-axis in my experimental plot from time to position.
Y is the distance spanned by the interference patterns and L is the distance from the slits to the aperture, which I measured to be 20.5mm, or 20500000nm, since all my length measurements are in nanometers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a physics question and has already been posted on the physics site.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a physics question, not a Mathematica question (and this answer should really be a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet).

One immediate concern is that your abscissa axis in the Excel plot has units of time, so it's unclear what transformation needs to happen to your data for you to compare to any model.

Discrepancies between theoretical models/predictions and observed results can arise from many different sources, both experimental and mathematical.

Comment: Agreed.  A physics question (since it involves comparing theory to an *experiment*).

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind for future posts.